# Gmail account login with Python requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

On multiple login pages, a google login is required in order to proceed. I would like to use requests library in python in order to log myself in. Normally this would be easy with the requests library, however I have not been able to get it to work. I am not sure if this is due to some restriction Google has made, or if it is because the Google login page requires the user to enter their email first, then press submit, and then enter their password, etc.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = r'https://accounts.google.com'
response = requests.get(login_url)

# Parse the HTML to find the form and its action URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
form = soup.find('form')
form_action = form['action']

# Extract the form fields and values
form_data = {}
for input_field in form.find_all('input'):
    name = input_field.get('name')
    value = input_field.get('value')
    form_data[name] = value

# Submit the form
form_data['identifier'] = 'your_email@gmail.com' # Replace with your Gmail address
response = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com'+form_action, data=form_data)

response = requests.get(response.url)

# Parse the HTML to find the form and its action URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
form = soup.find('form')
form_action = form['action']
# Extract the form fields and values
form_data = {}
for input_field in form.find_all('input'):
    name = input_field.get('name')
    value = input_field.get('value')
    form_data[name] = value
# Submit the form
form_data['passwd'] = 'your_password' # Replace with your password


response = requests.post(response.url, data=form_data)
# # Check the response to see if the login was successful
if 'Welcome to Gmail' in response.text:
    print('Login successful!')
else:
    print('Login failed.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script to access the https://myaccount.google.com/ site.

- Go to the url and log in.
- Open dev tools and insert the `__Secure-1PSID` and `__Secure-OSID` cookies into the code.
- If you are trying to log in to another site, change the domain in the `__Secure-OSID` cookie.
- Change the useragent string to [your useragent](https://ifconfig.me/)

The script will list your username.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()

# change to your useragent string
session.headers.update({"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5026.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1254.0"})

# copy your cookies from google site you want to access
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", "<your __Secure-1PSID cookie>", domain=".google.com", secure=True)
# do not forget to change domain
session.cookies.set("__Secure-OSID", "<your __Secure-OSID cookie>", domain="myaccount.google.com", secure=True)

data = session.get("https://myaccount.google.com/")
data.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, "html.parser")

# finds your name
name = soup.find("header", class_="R3PZhd").find("h1", class_="XY0ASe").text

print(name)
```

Comment: `  File "H:\Office Project\SerFox\Demo\Demo1\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    name = soup.find("header", class_="R3PZhd").find("h1", class_="XY0ASe").text
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: @AnikSaha That means `cookies` or `useragent` is wrong and google was unable recognize the user. The solution works for me. **Did you paste the cookies from `https://myaccount.google.com`? Did you provided your own user agent?**